# Invalid object graph in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a GiftCards table in my DBML that has a related property called Audit. The Audits are stored in a separate table. Each Audit has a related Person associated to it. There is also a Persons table. The relationships are set up and are valid in my DBML.

The problem is that when I instantiate a new Gift Card I also create a new related Audit in the OnCreated() method. But at the same time, I also create a related Person when I instantiate a new Audit. The Person is the current user. Actually the Audit's OnCreated method checks if the user already exists.

The problem is that when I instantiate a new gift Card, it also creates an associated Audit, which is fine, and the Audit creates an associated Person. But the Person already exists in the database. When I look at the data context's GetChangeSet(), it shows 3 inserts. The Persion should not show as an insert because he already exists in the database.

Here is how I implemented this. It is an MVC application where the Controller receives a gift card:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(GiftCardViewModel giftCard)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            GiftCard gc = GiftCardViewModel.Build(giftCard);
            repository.InsertOrUpdate(gc);
            repository.Save();
            return View("Consult", new GiftCardViewModel(repository.Find(gc.GiftCardID)));
        }
        else
            SetupContext();
        return View("_Form", giftCard);
    }
```

The Gift Card has:

```
partial class GiftCard
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        // Set up default audit.
        this.Audit = new Audit();
    }
}
```

The Audit class has:

```
partial void OnCreated()
    {
        // Setup timestamp
        this.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

        this.Person = Person.GetPerson(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
    }
```

And finally, my Person class has:

```
public static Person GetPerson(String username)
    {
        using (GiftCardDBDataContext database = new GiftCardDBDataContext())
        {
            // Try to get the person from database
            Person person = database.Persons.SingleOrDefault(personData => SqlMethods.Like(personData.Username, username));

            if (person == null)
            {
                person = new Person()
                {
                    Username = username,
                    FullName = "Full name TBD"
                };
                database.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
                database.SubmitChanges();
            }

            // Return person data
            return person;
        }
    }
```

When I create a new gift card, I always get an error saying that it's attempting to insert a duplicate person in the Persons table. I don't understand because my static class specifically checks if the Person already exists, if yes, I return the Person and I don't create a new one. Yet, the GetChangeSet() shows three inserts including the Person, which is wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue here is that you're using multiple contexts. You have one being created by your repository, and another is created in the static method on your Person object. You also aren't making any effort to attach the Person created/retrieved from the other context to the context of your Audit class.

You should look at a single unit of work, a single DataContext class, and perform all your work in that.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I decided to pass the data context as a parameter to my static GetPerson and it worked.